# Convergence of a random series

Tags: probability-theory

Fix $p \in (0,1)$. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots,$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribution $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = 1-p$. Consider $\bar{X}_k = X_k - p$, $k = 1,2, \ldots$

Define $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ and $\bar{S}_n = \bar{X}_1 + \cdots + \bar{X}_n$.

I hold like to prove that, as $n$ goes to infinity

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \bar{X}_{k+1} \frac{\bar{S}_k}{S_k} \right) \longrightarrow 0, $$

almost surely or in probability.

Ps: From Law of Large Number $S_k \sim pk$, and if i replace $S_k$ by $k$ above, i can use Markov's inequality to obtain the convergence in probability. But i can't use this approximation because of the dependence on the series terms...

Comment: I assume $\eta_k=0$ for all $k$?

Comment: Was a typing error, thanks.

Comment: If you divide by $n^{1/2 + \epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$ (instead of dividing by $n^{1/2}$) then it goes to zero with probability 1 (by a Chernov-Hoeffding argument).  Dividing by $n^{1/2}$ seems to be a pesky borderline case.

Comment: If you change $X_{k+1}$ in the sum to $\overline{X}_{k+1}$ it is a different story.

Comment: A minor comment, with $\bar{X}_k$ you mean the Bernoulli random variable with opposite probabilities?

Comment: No, $\bar{X}_k$ is $X_k$ centered.  $\bar{X}_k = X_k - p$.

Answer (score 1):

I have find a solution for convergence in probability. I decided to post it here because may be useful for someone in the future.

We can rewrite our expression in the following way:

\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \bar{X}_{k+1} \frac{\bar{S}_k}{S_k} \right) &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \bar{X}_{k+1} \frac{\bar{S}_k}{pk} \right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\bar{X}_{k+1} \bar{S}_k \left( \frac{1}{S_k} - \frac{1}{pk} \right) \right] \\ 
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \bar{X}_{k+1} \frac{\bar{S}_k}{pk} \right) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \bar{X}_{k+1}   \frac{\bar{S}_k^2}{pkS_k}  \right)\\ &:=& A_n - B_n. 
\end{eqnarray}

First note that $A_n$ converge to $0$ in probability. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, we have that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( |A_n| > \varepsilon \right) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(A_n^2)}{\varepsilon^2} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2 n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\mathbb{E}(\bar{X}_{k+1}^2) \mathbb{E}(\bar{S}_k^2)}{p^2k^2} = \frac{\mathbb{E}(\bar{X}_{1}^2)}{p^2 \varepsilon^2 n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = o(1).$$

For $B_n$, Law of large numbers states that, almost surely exists $k_1$ such that $S_k > (pk)/2$ for every $k \geq k_1$. And Law of iterated logarithm states that, given $\delta > 0$, almost surely exists $k_2$ such that $|\bar{S}_{k}| \leq k^{1/2 + \delta}$ for every $k > k_2$. In particular, for $k > k_0 =\max\{k_1, k_2\}$,

$$ |B_n| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left| \sum_{k=1}^{k_0} \left( \bar{X}_{k+1}   \frac{\bar{S}_k^2}{pkS_k}  \right) \right| + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=k_0 + 1}^{n} \left( |\bar{X}_{k+1}|\left| \frac{2k^{1+2\delta}}{p^2k^2}\right| \right).$$

Choosing $\delta < 1/4$, the last inequality imply that $|B_n|$ goes to $0$ almost sure.

Therefore, we have conclude that $A_n - B_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.